# Unable to reference Microsoft.Device namespace

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I'm unable to reference the `Microsoft.Devices` namespace to use [this class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.devices.vibratecontroller%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) to vibrate.

I can manually reference it from assembly `Microsoft.Phone.dll`, found in:

> c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\WindowsPhone\v8.1\Tools\AppDeploy\MdilXapCompilev8.0\Framework\Microsoft.Phone.dll

It worked, but when I try to compile it gives me an error:

> Cannot find type System.SystemException in module mscorlib.dll.

It's a Blank Windows Phone Project from VS 2013. I've tried reinstalling the SDK but it had no effect.

Comment: I edited your question to remove the Thank you, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) why we don't require that kind of stuff.

Comment: Seems little odd, but ok.

Comment: You cannot reference that assembly, very important that projects only use reference assemblies, not implementation assemblies.  The Phone 8.1 SDK is in beta right now, best to record your problem at connect.microsoft.com

Comment: I've reinstalled SDK 8.1 to SDK 8.0 and it keeps throwing an error.
I have similiar problem as this guy here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/4c2fe60a-9299-4740-a568-3f1e3e0c828e/cannot-find-type-systemsystemexception-in-module-mscorlibdll

but i'm just trying to use Microsoft.Devices namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally figured it out.

SDK 8.1 in RC 2 update for VS 2013 is not removable so you can't create SDK 8.0 project.
Reinstalling VS 2013 did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This one can solve your problem without need remove SDK 8.1 and degrade to 8.0: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn611853.aspx